# Is there a way to find out what elements are above an element in the DOM hierarchy with requests HTML

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, python-requests-html

I am working on a project in python using requests-html to web scrape and I've come across an issue where a section of HTML on the website I am trying to scrape is structured the same in 2 places (one for mobile and one for desktop). When I use the .find() method it grabs both of them. The only way to tell them apart is by the id of the div above them. Does anyone know if there is a way to search for elements above another element kind of like the opposite of .find().

Answer (score 0):

You could always locate the parent element you want with the correct id, then from there you can find all the child elements:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession()

with HTMLSession() as s:
    r = s.get(url)
    target = r.html.find('tag#id_of_choice', first=True)
    elems = target.find('tag')
```